# Is it possible to have multiple inputs in a neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, data-science

I have 2 different inputs where the second one is the output of the first (visible in the image- note that I have not included all of the lines between the network).
I'm trying to build a network where between the first input and the second there is one or more dense layers (fully connected layers), and then between the second input and the output there is again, one or more dense layers.
Is this possible?

The network I'm trying to build:
[image: The network I'm trying to build]

I have started by defining my network like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(num_neurons, input_dim=input, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(output, activation='softmax'))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(num_neurons, input_dim=input, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(output, activation='softmax'))
```

Since the inputs are a vector I didn't know if maybe using RNN/LSTM is even possible.

Should I go for a different network design?

Comment: I'm not sure where you got this neural network design from, but only first neuron of input layer gets propagated to the output (so it only considers the first feature)

Comment: I really appreciate your comment! I was wondering if what I'm trying to design is possible in some way (not necessarily the way I designed it)

Comment: Yep, but you would have to create weight matrices on your own as those are not standard fully connected layers and would have to multiply those by hand with the inputs appropriately.

Comment: I was leaning towards that solution, but I was wondering if Keras has something similar. Suppose I create 4 different weight matrices (one for the first input to first FC, second from FC to second input, third from second input to second FC, and fourth from FC to output), how would you go about the backpropagation/training the model?

Comment: Using [`tf.eager`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager#eager_training), creating custom layers, maybe creating custom layer in Keras or PyTorch, each of those options should be fine, my personal taste would go with the last one though.

Comment: I'm a bit new to the field so I'm not really sure what you mean by costum layer in Keras. Could you clarify? Thank you again by the way for all your help. You've been super

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the network using Keras Functional API!
It appeared like it allow for much more diversification in the network, allowing many inputs and outputs.